# Why my two-dimensional table does not display correctly?

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm writting a program where I set the number of rows and columns. After that values are given the program has to create a two-dimensional table and ask to fill each table cell. When everything is done the program has to display the data as a matrix. However when it comes to displaying the data some values are doubled while some are gone

I've tried to find any errors in code or in my way of thinking, but it seems fine for me though

```cpp
// when x and y are given these two loops should create and display the table
  for(int w = 1;w<x; w++)
    {
        for(int k = 1;k<y; k++)
        {
       cout<<"Set the value of the cell with coordinates: "<<w<<","<<k<<" = ";
       cin>>tab[w][k];
        }
    }
     for(int w = 1;w<x; w++)
    {
        for(int k = 1;k<y; k++)
        {
            cout<<tab[w][k]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

I expect the program to display a matrix with a certain number of rows and columns and recently given values for every cell. Unfortunately, when for instance I set: 3 rows, 2 columns and give values: 1,2,3,4,5,6(one for every cell) I receive in matrix:
1 3
3 5
5 6
My compilator shows neither no errors, nor warnings.

Comment: You should probably start at 0

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Where do you declare `tab` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ first element of an array has the index equal to 0 so your loops should be changed to:

```
 for(int w = 0;w<x; w++)
{
    for(int k = 0;k<y; k++)
    {
   cout<<"Set the value of the cell with coordinates: "<<w+1<<","<<k+1<<" = ";
   cin>>tab[w][k];
    }
}
 for(int w = 0;w<x; w++)
{
    for(int k = 0;k<y; k++)
    {
        cout<<tab[w][k]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you give 3 as `X` value and 2 as `Y` value you cant fill 6 cells because first loop will be from 1 to < 3 (execute 2 times) second loop 1 to < 2 (execute 1 time). Your loop must start from 0.